# Multi-class image classification problem with very little data for train or test

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a machine learning project. For data, I have 200k photos and each photo represent one class, so I will have 200k classes (e.g. I could have 200k images of rare bird, in which there is only one image available for each of them. Now, the problem is which method should I use for image detection with so little data?
Thank you.

Comment: I found this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/adventures-in-pytorch-image-classification-with-caltech-birds-200-part-1-the-dataset-6e5433e9897c) regarding bird species classification using Machine Learning. You can try that, and if that doesn't work for you, I'd suggest looking into [Transfer Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-hands-on-guide-to-transfer-learning-with-real-world-applications-in-deep-learning-212bf3b2f27a)

Comment: With this little data you can pretty much exclude all deep learning approaches. You could try a multi class SVM, they tend to perform better for sparse training sets.